# Heroku Error with Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Rails App has been working great for the past months. But when I just recently deployed another version of my Rails app to Heroku. I get the familiar error:

`We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.`

My logs are providing the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass)
```

The above error is referring to the following code: The following is a snippet from my welcome view `index.html.erb`.

```
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title" style="font-family: Dosis">My Latest Blog Post</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <h2><%= @article.title %></h2>
                      <p class="w3-opacity">Posted on <%= @article.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></p>
                      <hr>
                      <p><%= @article.text.first(700) %>. . .</p><br>
                      <%= link_to "Finish Reading", article_path(@article), class: "btn btn-default btn-block" %>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
```

Everything works perfect on localhost.

Below is the relevant controller and routes files:
welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @article = Article.order(created_at: :desc).first
   end
end
```

And here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'

  devise_for :users
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'

  get 'recipes/index'
  get 'articles/index'
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'

  resources :articles

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Any Ideas what it is tripping over?

Comment: You didn't forget to set Env variables nor run migrations?

Comment: those are not the logs, that's just the deployment. viewing the logs is like when you view the server log in your console when running the app locally

Comment: `@article` must be `nil`. can you post the relevant controller, routes, and request?

Answer (score 1):

That log only shows the deployment steps. To see application logs of runtime (which include all requests made against your app) you have to run `heroku logs --app <app-name>` from terminal or you can access it via [Heroku control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYYoy.png)